# Can't see react page after serving data with .net core api

Tags: c#, reactjs, api, asp.net-core

I want to show data in my react component but when I set API react doesn't work. It seems like middleware is setup wrong or I don't get how .net core and react go along. I know I basically run two different apps with .net core and react but somebody could tell me how to resolve my problem to just put this API data in react page? I made it with approach model first using Entity framework.

I tried to change middleware but in the end, API is always shown. When I change the routing of API, react works fine so everything is good with set up to react. But when they are two on the same route. I only see data from API. And i only want to get data from .net core and show it in react component.

UsersController.cs

```
[Route("[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class UsersController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly MafiaContext _context;

    public UsersController(MafiaContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    // GET: Users
    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<User>>> GetUsers()
    {
        return await _context.Users.ToListAsync();
    }
```

app.js

```
  <Layout>
    <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
    <Route path="/users" component={User} /> //this one is a route for the api
    <Route path="/counter" component={Counter} />
    <Route path="/fetch-data" component={FetchData} />
  </Layout>
```

Startup.cs

public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

```
    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);

        services.AddDbContext<MafiaContext>(options =>
            options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DevConnection")));

        // In production, the React files will be served from this directory
        services.AddSpaStaticFiles(configuration =>
        {
            configuration.RootPath = "ClientApp/build";
        });
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
            // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
            app.UseHsts();
        }

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseStaticFiles();
        app.UseSpaStaticFiles();

        app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                template: "{controller}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });

        app.UseSpa(spa =>
        {
            spa.Options.SourcePath = "ClientApp";

            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                spa.UseReactDevelopmentServer(npmScript: "start");
            }
        });
    }
}
```

I want to grab data that is shown in the picture [image: Picture]and put it in the react table.

Comment: This is probably one of the reasons its nice to use a route like "api/[controller]"

Comment: Thank you for your answer. So I should stick with it when I'm creating a user account or should I get a different approach?